# Pandas groupby and create max or sum based on critera of another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm having trouble reconciling a few different posts for my own use case, but believe I'm close.

I have a data frame with 3 columns; user, flag, hours.

I want to group the data frame by user and create a new column that, based on the flag value, either sum or take the max value of hours rows. Each user has two rows.

So it looks like this:

```
User: 1 Flag: 0 Hours: 2
User: 1 Flag: 0 Hours: 3

User: 2 Flag: 1 Hours: 1
User: 2 Flag: 1 Hours: 3

User: 3 Flag: 2 Hours: 1
User: 3 Flag: 2 Hours: 2
```

I'd like to create a new column called 'Agg' that either sums the two rows or takes the max value of the rows depending on the flag. If the flag is 0 the sum, if the flag is 1 then max, if the flag is 2 then max. I'm calling out flag 1 and flag 2 separately even though the outcome is the same because I may change the logic later.

So the outcome would be so:

```
User: 1 Flag: 0 Hours: 2 Agg: 5
User: 1 Flag: 0 Hours: 3 Agg: 5

User: 2 Flag: 1 Hours: 1 Agg: 3
User: 2 Flag: 1 Hours: 3 Agg: 3

User: 3 Flag: 2 Hours: 1 Agg: 2
User: 3 Flag: 2 Hours: 2 Agg: 2
```

This is what I have so far, but I can't get it to work properly. Forgive my newbie coding.

```
group = sample.groupby('User')
sample[:,'Agg'] =group.apply(lambda grp: grp['Hours'].max() if grp['Flag'] == 1 elif grp['Flag']==2 else grp['Hours'].sum())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
groups = df.groupby('User')['Hours']
df['Agg'] = np.where(df['Flag'].astype(bool),
                     groups.transform('max'),
                     groups.transform('sum'))
```

if there are more case you could use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
np.select([df['Flag'].eq(0), df['Flag'].isin([1,2])],
          [groups.transform('sum'), groups.transform('max')])
```

Comment: thank you @ansev , how does the code identify max for flag 1 or 2 and sum for flag 0? Also I'm having trouble running this as I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' `

Comment: 0 is interpreted as false and the rest is interpreted as true

Comment: It seems the problem is your dataframe, surely you need to use `.loc` or `.iloc`

Comment: one minor follow-up, say one of the two rows for a user has a Flag 0: and the second row indicates Flag: 2. Is it possible to groupby and use contains to say, treat this user as Flag: 2?

Comment: yes, you could use `flag = df.groupby('User')['Flag'].transform('max')` and then use `np.select([flag.eq(0), flag.isin([1,2])],
          [groups.transform('sum'), groups.transform('max')])`

Comment: it also depends on what you are doing specifically